# Не могу найти теги, в которых информация. bs4

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

bs4 не находит теги article.
Как его найти?
Вот кусок кода:

```
url = 'https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--noutbuki-v-beloretske/54544/list?hid=91013&page=2&onstock=1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
cards = soup.find_all('article', class_ = '_1_IxNTwqll')
print(cards)
# Выводит: []
```

Вот сайт: https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--noutbuki-v-beloretske/54544/list?hid=91013&page=2&onstock=1

Help! Please.

Comment: А почему 'lxml'? На сайте вроде html используется

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего, вы натыкаетесь на captcha.
Вы можете проверить это распечатав ответ.
В ответе можно увидеть многократно повторяющееся слово "captcha".

```
r = requests.get(url).text
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. метод get из модуля requests возвращает обьект класса Response, а BeautifulSoup в свою очередь принимает готовый html текст
2. проверьте ваш html и увидите что у вас выходит captcha вместо требуемой страницы, на счет обхода captcha есть множество материалов, посмотрите про proxy и user-agent например

   ```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = 'https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--noutbuki-v-beloretske/54544/list?hid=91013&page=2&onstock=1'
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.text

    print(html)  # возвращает html со страницей капчи

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    cards = soup.find_all('article', class_ = '_1_IxNTwqll')
    print(cards) # пустой список так на странице с капчей нет нужных элементов
   ```